# Error when truncating the sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

I am naming sheets using :

```
            arrayCollabName = Array("CBDeltaBlockStatus_SAP03_to_Delta01", "CBDeltaBlockStatus_SAP03_to_Delta02", "CBDeltaDeliveryInformation_SAP03_to_Delta01") 

            If Len(arrayCollabName(idx)) > 31 Then
                 ActiveSheet.Name = Left(arrayCollabName(idx), 31)
            Else
                 ActiveSheet.Name = arrayCollabName(idx)
            End If
```

In the array 1st and 2nd  names are similar when the name gets truncated to 31 characters and VB is throwing the error "Cannot rename the sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by visualbasic."

Any way I can do this without error and name the sheets as **CBDeltaBlock_SAP03_to_Delta01** and **CBDeltaBlock_SAP03_to_Delta02** or any desired name.

Comment: Yes you can. For that you will have to use error handling or check if the sheet exists (in a loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to change the sheet name if it already exists.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strShName As String

    strShName = "BlahBlah"

    Sheets.Add

    Do Until DoesSheetExist(strShName) = False
        i = Int((1000 * Rnd) + 1)
        strShName = strShName & i
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Name = strShName
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(ByVal strSheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

The above method will add a random number at the end of the sheet. If you want in increasing order then use the below code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strShName As String

    strShName = "BlahBlah"

    Sheets.Add

    If DoesSheetExist(strShName) = True Then
        i = 1
        Do Until DoesSheetExist(strShName & i) = False
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        strShName = strShName & i
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Name = strShName
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(ByVal strSheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

**NOTE**: The above code are just sample codes. Error Handling has not been incorporated in the above code and needless to say that Error handling is a must :)